# Shuffling colors in an array to 5 divs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, colors, shuffle

Newly into the world of development so please be patient if i lack xp.  I need to put 5 specific colors (I'm assuming using an array and shuffle function) in my 5 circles randomly.

**HTML**

```
<div id="colorBox"> 
    <div class="circle"></div>          
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>          
    <div class="circle"></div>          
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
        temporaryValue, randomIndex;


    while (0 !== currentIndex) {


        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}

var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'pink'];
shuffle(colors);

$(".circle").css("background", colors);
```

I just dont understand what is wrong with my code. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting array of colors but background need single value not array
moreover you need to set it on each separately.

Try like this

```
var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'pink'];
shuffle(colors);
var i = 0;
$(".circle").each(function() {
    $(this).css("background", colors[i++]);

});
```

Comment: I guess i forgot to mention i only want one of each color.   So the top example wont work.   Thank you for your help

Comment: @ReptarNation  ok, i removed that but you need .each to use value

Comment: Oh ok I understand it was trying to give the colors as a whole instead of the individual div.   Thank you so much been working on that for way too long.

Comment: Although Anik is correct that you need to set each circle individually, this method does not answer the question completely.

Comment: @A.Sharma , op didn't ask about shuffling .. op ask about not setting color . answer is partial or full but that's not mean that you'll give downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Let's think about this for a second. Let's say your first `randomIndex` comes from an `array.length` of **5**. The result comes out to be `randomIndex` is equal to **2**. Once the `currentIndex` is reduced by a value of 1, the next selection size is out of **4**. What happens if you get a `randomIndex` of **2** again? You have overwritten your first CSS styling. What you need to be doing is removing the color from the array after you use it:

```
function shuffle(array) {

  var randomIndex;
  var currentIndex = 0;

  while (0 !== array.length) {

    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    var arrayColor = array[randomIndex];

    if (randomIndex > -1) //this cond. statement will remove the array element
     {
      array.splice(randomIndex,1);                 
     }

    $(".circle").eq(currentIndex).css("background", arrayColor); // Set each circle starting at element zero with the "eq" method
    currentIndex++;
 }

}

var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'pink'];
shuffle(colors);
```

See the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2q1g4v79/).

Ultimately what I have done is used a combination of `array.splice` as well as include the CSS styling of the JQuery **WITHIN** the loop. This solves the issue highlighted by Anik. If you plan on setting the styling of each circle, then you need to do it within a looping statement/method.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

**Javavscript**

```
var colors = shuffle(['red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'pink']);
$(".circle").each(function(index) {
  $(this).css("background", colors[index]);
});

function shuffle(arr) {
  for (i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var temp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = temp;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="colorBox">
    <div class="circle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="circle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="circle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="circle">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="circle">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `.css(propertyName, function)` , `Array.prototype.slice()`, `Array.prototype.splice()`

```js
var colors = ["red", "blue", "green", "black", "pink"], c;

$(".circle").css("backgroundColor", function(index, value) {
    // if `index` : `0` define `c` as copy of `colors` array
    if (!index) c = colors.slice();
    return c.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * c.length), 1)
});
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="colorBox">
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```